# How can i see the burndown chart for each sprint on TFS Web Access?

Tags: tfs, tfs-web-access, burndowncharts

How can i add the current sprint iteration burn-down chart to the home page on TFS Web Access? Here is a burn-down chart below that shows nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no data in your sprint. If there is data in your sprint your burn down will display.

You need to have:

- Tasks within Scope of the sprint
- Tasks to have a value of Remaining Work

[image]

One you have that, on the second day you will see a burn down. As you change Remaining Work on that second day you will also see a dynamic change in the burn down.

Comment: I painted the picture. You can see the work items. Each work items have remaining work. :(

Comment: You 8 Features in progress. I see no Remaining Work on Tasks as the "o of o h" indicates. How many Tasks appear on the Sprint Backlog and what is the sum of the remaining work?

Answer (score 0):

After ensuring you have the remaining hours set up, and the corresponding iterations --

Under the tools option > Control panel > drill down to project

Select Work tab > iterations > Access click here on "To access the default team's iteration settings"

Below you will see which iterations are displayed. Select iteration > choose iterations, whether current and/or future ones